# Enable “mouse keys” booted to installer/recovery?

Tags: install, recovery, accessibility, mouse-keys

The installer/recovery partition MAKES you connect a mouse. Is there any way to bypass this requirement (and enable mouse keys) while booted to the Mac Installer / Recovery partition?

Comment: I did it once, and can't remember how, and now I'm searching for the same answer.  The Reinstall macOS utility REQUIRES a mouse to choose the hard drive to install to (even when there is only one).  Very frustrating.

Comment: Problem solved: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/454485/how-to-install-macos-with-no-mouse-or-trackpad/454528#454528